# Column order does not hold in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.7.2

I am adding columns in this order

```cs
var tblCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
tblCol.HeaderText = "Table Name";
tblCol.ReadOnly = true;
tblCol.Width = 300;
tblCol.DataPropertyName = "TableName";

grdTableSelect.Columns.Add(tblCol);

var boolCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
boolCol.HeaderText = "Insert";
boolCol.ReadOnly = false;
boolCol.Width = 50;
boolCol.DataPropertyName = "Insert";

grdTableSelect.Columns.Add(boolCol);

boolCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
boolCol.HeaderText = "Update";
boolCol.ReadOnly = false;
boolCol.Width = 50;
boolCol.DataPropertyName = "Update";

grdTableSelect.Columns.Add(boolCol);

boolCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
boolCol.HeaderText = "Delete";
boolCol.ReadOnly = false;
boolCol.Width = 50;
boolCol.DataPropertyName = "Delete";

grdTableSelect.Columns.Add(boolCol);

tblCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
tblCol.HeaderText = "Status";
tblCol.ReadOnly = true;
tblCol.Width = 250;
tblCol.DataPropertyName = "Status";

grdTableSelect.Columns.Add(tblCol);
```

Item Model

```cs
private class TableGridItem
{


    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public bool? Insert {get; set;}
    
    public bool? Delete {get; set;}
    
    public bool? Update {get; set;}
    
}
```

But the `Status` column for some reason ends up #3 prepositionally

[image]

I need `status` to be #4. **Additionally** - prior to today, without `Status` column and property in the item model, it worked as desired.

Comment: Each grid column has a `DisplayIndex` property... `dataGridView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 2;`

Comment: @JohnG I added to each column `tblCol.DisplayIndex = 0...4` Same result. I have to add that prior to today, without `Status`, it worked as desired

Comment: is the word Status something special? What if you rename to other such as Sutats?

Comment: @LeiYang Without data, binded to empty list, it displayed as desired with `Status`

Comment: i'd like to debug if you can commit a demo in github.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the data source and let the grid auto generate the columns, it may give a hint as to why this is happening. In addition, if the `DisplayIndex` of the column is something greater than the total number of columns, then obviously something may not work.

Example, if you set the first columns `DispalyIndex` to 4, THEN "add" the column to the grid, then obviously there is no “index” 4. Therefore, instead of setting the `DisplayIndex` when you create the columns… Set the `DisplayIndex` “after” all the columns have been added and the data source has been set.… Something like…

```
  grdTableSelect.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 0;
  grdTableSelect.Columns[1].DisplayIndex = 4;
  grdTableSelect.Columns[2].DisplayIndex = 2;
  grdTableSelect.Columns[3].DisplayIndex = 3;
  grdTableSelect.Columns[4].DisplayIndex = 1;
```

Or you could simply change the order of the properties in the `TableGridItem` class… something like…

```
public class TableGridItem {

  public string TableName { get; set; }

  public bool? Insert { get; set; }

  public bool? Delete { get; set; }

  public bool? Update { get; set; }

  public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think, you're into something here. I will only tell you that when I ran this without data, empty list, it displayed as desired. Let me try something here before I can tell you more

Comment: You were close. Change the answer. On Binding Complete I did what you did only instead of index I gave each column a name during setup and did `grdTableSelect.Columns["colStatus"].DisplayIndex = 4]`. With index `Status` moved to #1 position instead of #4

Comment: I would think the simplest solution would be to change the order of the properties in the `TableGridItem` class. No code is needed to set the column order if this change is made… at least this is what my test showed. In addition the only reason I used a fixed number to identify the column was because you did not have the code that named each column… so I used the index.

Comment: I totally understand what you're saying, But I would rather have this explicitly set and not relied on some type reflection. Mostly for those who come after me, because it is a little confusing. Actually, extremely interesting - It has to be a reflection, when no column mapping added. But I don't remember `PropertyInfo` order. I would think, it would be lined up by name. And FINALLY, I have it fully working. With your guidance. But I will try just out of curiosity ... tomorow

Comment: I will also investigate. It seem that when I do `columns.add` it does not insert at the next index because calling `grdTableSelect.Columns[0]` does not seem to return column I added first

Comment: “Where” (what event) is the posted code executed from? I was doing this in the forms `Load` event.

Comment: Grid is built in constructor and column order is now set in `DataBindingComplete`. I also set some checkbox cells `readonly` there

Comment: I told you precisely. Replace `Columns[0]` with `Columns["someName"]` and tell me to give columns names, and what you posted will work. And I will accept your answer. I am not sure why you sound so fatigued.